# How to get Angular $http to work with ASP.NET C# Backend?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, ajax, xmlhttprequest

How can I use Angular $http to work with a ASP.NET WebForms and C# Backend? Would I have to write my own RESTful server? Please help a beginner!

Comment: You should use Web API.

Comment: What exactly it stopping you from using it?  Angular itself doesn't really care what server-side technology is used.  As long as the requests and responses work, it's fine.  Do you have an example of something that isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go with **Web API** project. But if you are forced to use **ASP.NET WebForms** then best way is to go with custom **IHttpHandler**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Web API project to expose REST endpoint for your web app.
2. In your angular web app create angular service to call REST endpoint created at the step 1.
3. Use angular service created in step 2 within your angular web app and profit.